# How to wireup an event that adds numeric html input values for a slots game

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a slot machine and I'm new to programming, so this will probably be a easy fix for people.

When I try this

```
var money = document.getElementsByName('money')[0].value;
var bet = document.getElementsByName('bet$')[0].value;


var winnings = Number(bet) + Number(money);
$('#money').val(winnings);
```

it only lets me bet the value of the input which is 10

I want to have the current bet to be added to the current money and then I want the sum to be displayed in the money input box.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="betbox">
  <button id="bet">Bet</button>
  <input type="number" id="bet$" name="bet$" value="10" />
</div>

<div id="moneybox">
  <input type="text" id="money" name="money" value="100" />
</div>
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you should use `$("input[name=money]").val()` instead.

Comment: you do realise the # in `$('#money')` means id right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sum of two input value by jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552959/sum-of-two-input-value-by-jquery)

Comment: Is your initial value 10?  Might be obvious, but are you tracking the changes value?  if the code only executes once that might be your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var current = $("#money"),
    bet = $("#bet$");

var updatedTotal = Number(current.val()) + Number(bet.val());
current.val(updatedTotal);
```

Documentation on selectors, events, dom manipulation, etc can all be found here.

http://jquery.com/

To take this a bit further you can write this in such a way that you have:

```
<div id="betbox">
     <button id="bet">Bet</button>
     <input type="number" id="bet$" name="bet$" value="10" />
</div>

<div id="moneybox">
     <input type="text" id="money" name="money" value="100" />
</div>
```

Then your script element will look like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function(){
          $("#bet").on("click",function(){
               var current = $("#money"),
                   bet = $("#bet$");

              var updatedTotal = Number(current.val()) + Number(bet.val());
              current.val(updatedTotal);

              FetchNextBet();
          });
     });

     function FetchNextBet()
     {
          var newBet = window.prompt("You win, please enter a new bet!");
          if(Number(newBet) > updatedTotal)
          {
                alert("You cannot bet more money than you have!");
                FetchNextBet();
          }
          else
          {
                bet.val(newBet);
          }
     }
</script>
```

Comment: this seems to be working, but the first bet must be 10, and if i bet over 100 after the first then it enters the negatives

Comment: I added some logic around how to make this bet work and run more than once.  FetchNextBet allows the user to enter a new bet after winning the current round.  You can use some of the same logic in the actual button click example I provided to check to make sure the bet is valid.  But this should give you a starting point to do everything you want to do.

Comment: Since you have the generic username and 1 reputation I'm guessing your new.  Be sure to click the up arrow and accept the answer if it solves your problem so the question can then be closed appropriately.