# Multiplying text field tag values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Hello everybody i'm using rails 2.3.5 and ruby 1.8.7
   I'm trying to multiply 2 values in 2 field_field_tag also i'm not using the information of the model because i just want multiply 2 values

```
/PROJECT/app/views/reports/index.html.erb

  <%=  text_field_tag "mount",@mount %>
  <%=  text_field_tag "dolars",@dolars %>

  <%=  text_field_tag "total",@total %>
  <%= link_to 'CALCULATE',:controller=>"reports",:action=>"calculate" %>

/PROJECT/app/controllers/report.rb

  class CustomerReportsController < ApplicationController
    def calculate
       @total= @soles * @mount
       @mount= ""
    end
  end
```

Please can someone help me?  i will appreciate your help

---

```
 <%=  text_field_tag "mount",@mount %>
 <%=  text_field_tag "dolars",@dolars %>
 <%=  @total= @dolars * @mount %>
 <%=  text_field_tag "dolars",@dolars %>
```

i want to multiply the first value and the second value and have the answer on the total text field

Comment: It's hard to say what you are want to do. I understand you want to multiply values, but we need some context. It looks to me like you want to run before you can walk; I suggest you learn a bit or Ruby as well as Rails, judging by the code you have provided.

Comment: I know it's not the answer you probably want, but I agree with @Mohamad - your code makes it seem like you're trying to jump too far into the Rails deep end before really understanding the basics.

Start with this tutorial - http://ruby.railstutorial.org/, and make sure that you can get a basic app up and running.  It'll teach you more about how MVC works, and I think it'll be more clear to you how you need to refactor your code.  I promise it'll pay off in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that you're probably doing your calculation in the wrong place.

The best place to do your calculations is in the Model (the Report model in this case if you have one). In the controller, create the @total variable by calling whatever model method does your total calculation, and in the view, just write out the @total variable.

... then write unit tests to test your model calculates the total correctly.

Comment: SORRY ABOUT THAT BUT I TRIED ON THE MODEL I JUST ONLY WANT MULTIPLY 2 TEXT FIELD VALUES

Comment: Do you mean that you want to add the values as they're entered (without the page being submitted)? In which case you want to be looking at a client-side solution like Javascript/jQuery. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552959/sum-of-two-input-value-by-jquery

Comment: OK thanks it worked!!!!!! 
But do you know how use text_field or text_field_tag instead of INPUTS??

Comment: Rails form helper information is here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag

Comment: maybe also look at creating a simple model scaffold, using the rails scaffold generator, and look at the generated code for an example of how to use the form helpers.