# jquery for dynamic addition of two numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've had a search but haven't found anything that is really what I'm trying to do.

I have a dynamic form which has 2 input boxes per item, 1 being a value `cldAmount` and the other being a `cldAmount_1` and want to calculate sum into field `cldAmount_2` (for example).

I was hoping I would find something that will work with unlimited items.

```
<form:input path="ewsLookupList[${status.index}].collateralDetails.cldAmount" size="8"/>
```

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: am tried using jquery <form:input path="ewsLookupList[${status.index}].collateralDetails.cldAmount" size="8"/>

Comment: Please go through [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: am tried using jquery          <form:input path="ewsLookupList[${status.index}].collateralDetails.cldAmount" size="8"/>                      <form:input path="ewsLookupList[${status.index}].collateralDetails.cldAmount_1" size="8"/>                        <form:input path="ewsLookupList[${status.index}].collateralDetails.cldAmount_2" size="8"/>

Comment: Your question is not clear, please define what you have to do and what you have tried with screenshot (if possible)

Comment: i want function using jquery which calculates sum of two numbers unlimited times as my form is dynamic

Comment: even if unlimited fields, do you have index value

Comment: can u please give me example

Comment: something like this can work. loop through 0 to index. var pth = "ewsLookupList[" + indx + "].collateralDetails.cldAm‌​ount". var txt1 = $("input[path="+pth+"]").val():var txt2 = $("input[path="+pth+"_1]").val():$("input[path="+pth+"_2]").val(txt1+txt2):

Comment: <form:input  path="ewsLookupList[${status.index}].collateralDetails.cldAmount"  
size="8"/>

Comment: you mean something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552959/sum-of-two-input-value-by-jquery)?